issues with scaling winform, on high res at 125% the labels move and start to overlap
Im having issues with a desktop app I created, when I load it on my desktop it looks one way but when it loads to a computer with a higher screen resolution certain things move around and the appearance is bad. I have tried multiple things like using achors, changing dpi settings, setting min/max size, nothing seems to work. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
my computer-correct layout
2nd computer-layout moved
I have tried to set the anchors, enabled dpi awareness, disabled dpi awareness, set min size, set max size, set auto resize mode to none,set auto resize mode to DPI, set auto resize more to font.

You didn't specify the .NET version you're targeting. This information can never go missing -- You mentioned different methods, but those work in combination. What setting combos have you actually tried? Also considering that handling DPiAwareness is a design strategy: you have to explicitly build your app for that -- From what can be deciphered, based on the images, your Form is simply scaling to Font, and the child Controls are just added to the Form's surface, no specialized nested containers, as TableLayoutPanels etc.

If you think this description of the current Layout does not reflect your design, then post the content of the Form's designer.cs file
